# Bash script to compare files

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a folder with a ton of old photos with many duplicates. Sorting it by hand would take ages, so I wanted to use the opportunity to use bash.

Right now I have the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="~/Desktop/Test/*"
for file in ${directory};
do
    for filex in ${directory}:
    do
        if [ $( diff {$file} {$filex} ) == 0 ]
        then
            mv ${filex} ~/Desktop
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

And getting the exit code:

```
diff: {~/Desktop/Test/*}: No such file or directory
diff: {~/Desktop/Test/*:}: No such file or directory
File_compare: line 8: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

I've tried modifying working code I've found online, but it always seems to spit out some error like this. I'm guessing it's a problem with the nested for loop?

Also, why does it seem there are different ways to call variables? I've seen examples that use `${file}, "$file", and "${file}"`.

Comment: Try assigning the full path. `directory="/home/someuser/Desktop/Test/*" ` Alternatively, don't use quotes. `directory=~/Desktop/Test/*` It seems that quotes cause issues with expanding the tilde.

Comment: I'm not able to test it out right now, but I think I tried that and got the same errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the `{}` in the wrong places:

```
if [ $( diff {$file} {$filex} ) == 0 ]
```

They should be at:

```
if [ $( diff ${file} ${filex} ) == 0 ]
```

(though the braces are optional now), but you should allow for spaces in the file names:

```
if [ $( diff "${file}" "${filex}" ) == 0 ]
```

Now it simply doesn't work properly because when `diff` finds no differences, it generates no output (and you get errors because the `==` operator doesn't expect nothing on its left-side).  You could sort of fix it by double quoting the value from `$(…)` (`if [ "$( diff … )" == "" ]`), but you should simply and directly test the exit status of `diff`:

```
if diff "${file}" "${filex}"
then : no difference
else : there is a difference
fi
```

and maybe for comparing images you should be using `cmp` (in silent mode) rather than `diff`:

```
if cmp -s "$file" "$filex"
then : no difference
else : there is a difference
fi
```

Comment: I'll give that a show when I can. Can you just explain why you have `no difference`? I don't understand how that means "no output".

Comment: I mean that the `if diff …` tests the exit status of the `diff` command, and `diff` returns 0 (success) if the two files were identical and a non-zero (failure) status if the files were different (or one wasn't found, or …).  The `if` test therefore executes the `then` code when the files are the same (or there is no difference between them), or the `else` code when the files are different.  The `:` command is a shell built-in that gets its arguments evaluated and then succeeds — in this context, it is a no-op that you can replace with the code you want to execute the files are the same.  Etc.

Comment: The `diff` command will print differences to standard output if there are differences between the files.  You can redirect such output to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see it.  OTOH, using `cmp -s` already deals with that by not generating any output anyway.

Comment: Note that [Gordon Davisson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) also raises some valid issues in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41413224/) — you should heed both.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the problems Jonathan Leffler pointed out:

```
directory="~/Desktop/Test/*"
for file in ${directory};
```

`~` and `*` won't get expanded inside double-quotes; the `*` will get expanded when you use the variable without quotes, but since the `~` won't, it's looking for files under an directory actually named "~" (*not* your home directory), it won't find any matches. Also, as Jonathan pointed out, using variables (like `${directory}`) without double-quotes will run you into trouble with filenames that contain spaces or some other metacharacters. The better way to do this is to not put the wildcard in the variable, use it when you reference the variable, with the variable in double-quotes and the `*` outside them:

```
directory=~/"Desktop/Test"
for file in "${directory}"/*;
```

Oh, and another note: when using `mv` in a script it's a good idea to use `mv -i` to avoid accidentally overwriting another file with the same name.

And: use [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) to sanity-check your code and point out common mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

If you are simply interested in knowing if two files differ, `cmp` is the best option.  Its advantages are:

1. It works for text as well as binary files, unlike `diff` which is for text files only
2. It stops after finding the first difference, and hence it is very efficient

So, your code could be written as:

```
if ! cmp -s "$file" "$filex"; then
  # files differ...
  mv "$filex" ~/Desktop

  # any other logic here
fi
```

Hope this helps.  I didn't understand what you are trying to do with your loops and hence didn't write the full code.

Comment: I'm trying to take each `file` in the directory and compare it to every other file down the line, removing duplicates as it goes. Using the code now isn't working; it says everything is a duplicate. Here:

`for file in "${directory}"/*; do
 for filex in "${directory}"/*; do
  if cmp -s "$file" "$filex" 
  then
   :
  else
   mv -i "$filex" ~/Desktop
   echo "$filex"
  fi
 done 
done`

Comment: May be you shouldn't compare a file with itself.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's comparing the first file to itself each time... that does complicate things. Is there an easy way to avoid that?

Comment: I've tried doing: `if [ cmp -s "$file" "$filex" ] || ["$file" != "$filex" ]; `, but it still is giving problems.

Comment: Do the comparison only when file names are different t.  So you need && not ||.

Comment: Ah, I also had to change it to `if cmp -s "$file" "$filex" && [ "$file" != "$filex" ]`. This syntax is not very intuitive. It's working now, though, thanks.

Comment: I did some preliminary testing on it and it seemed to work great, but when I tried it out on the big set of photos, it's leaving a lot of duplicates. Every time I run the script, it picks up something new. There must be a logic error in my nested for loop. Oh, and it also takes a very long time. I actually think it may be because the photos have somehow been altered slightly, yet there is no visible difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff "$file" "$filex" &>/dev/null` and get the last command result with `$?` :

```
#!/bin/bash

SEARCH_DIR="."
DEST_DIR="./result"

mkdir -p "$DEST_DIR"

directory="."

ls $directory | while read file;
do
    ls $directory | while read filex;
    do
        if [ ! -d "$filex" ] && [ ! -d "$file" ] && [ "$filex" != "$file" ];
        then

            diff "$file" "$filex" &>/dev/null

            if [ "$?" == 0 ];
            then
                echo "$filex is a duplicate. Copying to $DEST_DIR"
                mv "$filex" "$DEST_DIR"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

Note that you can also use [fslint](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/fslint) or [fdupes](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/fdupes.1.html) utilities to find duplicates